# Sqlalchemy update json column using binaryexpression in python

Tags: python, json, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying too update the JSON datatype column of postgresql table using Sqlalchemy binaryexpression in python.

**Example**

```
unit_price = 10.10
final_data = {
    "price_details": {
        "unit_price":unit_price,
        "total_amt":testmodel.qty * unit_price
    }
}

test_db = session.query(testmodel).filter(testmodel.id >= 10)
test_db.update(final_data,synchronize_session=False)
```

In above example i am trying to calculate `total_amt` using binaryexpression. But I am getting error.

```
StatementError: (exceptions.TypeError) <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.BinaryExpression object at 0x6024810> is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use DB values in your update, you have to use the DB JSON features instead of passing serialized JSON from Python – not to mention that the Python JSON encoder has no idea what to do with an SQL expression. Consulting the [Postgresql JSON functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) it seems that `json_build_object()` or its JSONB variant are what you're looking for:

```
unit_price = 10.10
final_data = {
    "price_details": func.json_build_object(
        "unit_price", unit_price,
        "total_amt", testmodel.qty * unit_price
    )
}

test_db = session.query(testmodel).filter(testmodel.id >= 10)
test_db.update(final_data, synchronize_session=False)
```